# datasnap TSocketconnection hangs

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have a Datasnap application(Delphi 7) which uses TSocketConnectiom to connect to application server. If my application stays idle for a long time after opening a clientdataset, most of the times when i want to refresh the clientdataset the application freezes without raising any exceptions.It seems that the connection is dropped  and the Socketconnection is not aware of that.I am experiencing this problem very often and I am not sure where can I find the solution. Could it be a bug in TSocketconnection?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you checked `netstat` (a `DOS` utility) to see if your app still has a connection to the server?  You can use `netstat` on the client machine and on the server machine to see if both sides still show an `ESTABLISHED` connection.  You can also use a packet sniffer like Ethereal to capture the traffic if the server is running on a different machine than the client.  This has helped me in the past to troubleshoot communication issues -- to narrow down just where the issue occurs...

Comment: Thank you for your reply...  You mean before refreshing the client dataset I should check the connection with something else like netstat?

Comment: If the connection is established by a second client application after the first one is disconnected, what happens? Net stat shows Established connection but the Socketconnection is disconnected...

Comment: Each connection has a source port.  If you run `netstat` just after the initial connection is made, you should see the local port on the client machine that is used.  On the server side, you should see a connection has been established from the source port that was used on the client machine.  Then after you wait long enough for the issue to happen, run `netstat` again (w/o refreshing the client) on both the client and server side to see if the OS still sees the original connection as `ESTABLISHED`.  If other clients connect, they will have different source ports and different IP addresses...

Comment: If `netstat` and the `TSocketConnection` don't agree (only one shows connected), then you can start troubleshooting from there...  BTW - I have left an idle client connected to a DataSnap server for 24+ hours and it maintained the connection so that I could use it again without any problems.  I'm using XE2 though -- there may be some significant changes between Delphi 7 and XE2.

Comment: There is significant changes in DataSnap, which IIRC was rewritten in 2010. For example DataSnap now uses INDY as the TCP/IP library.

Comment: What is the best practice to work with socketconnectios? Should I frequently open and close the connection every time I want to do some transactions or the connection must be open always, regarding performance, as for every transaction the connection should be opened again and then closed?

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls sometimes drop inactive TCP connections after some time to keep their cache usage low. In this case it helps to call some server method (maybe every five minutes).

If the "setup and teardown" code for the server side DataSnap session is not to resource-consuming, you can also disconnect and reconnect the DataSnap client between all actions. This will initiate a fresh TCP connection, execute, and close it.

Comment: Is it possible to know why TSocketConnection(Datasnap) sometimes doesn't raise an exception when the connection is dropped?

Comment: If the client does not to try read or write, and the connection is lost, no exception will be raised. This is normal for TCP socket connections.

Comment: Ok, but when I want to query something it does not raise an Exception too.This is the scenario: Connection to Remote server is established, some data is read, then program goes into idle state for some long time, the connection is dropped at this time and no exception is raised, now when I want to read something I get no exception , just everything freeze and I should kill the process...

Comment: Maybe the socket operation timeout is too high. If the operation blocks the UI thread while waiting for the response, this would explain it. I don't know how the Datasnap stimeout can be set.

Comment: Remy said yesterday here something about Indy defaulting to infinite timeouts. MAybe you need to change the timeout for these server sockets so that they don't block infinitely, perhaps the infinite block is in the `select()` function in the winsock layer, and if so, then that's your only practical option.

Comment: @Warren in Delphi 7, DataSnap (or midas) was not over Indy.

Comment: Oops. I missed that part.  And MJN already mentioned socket timeouts.

Comment: I found that the code is locked here:  RetVal := select(0, @FDSet, nil, nil, TimeVal); somewhere in the connecting process...  I dont know where can i find the timeout...